# Dynamically creating buttons with popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I try to create buttons with popovers via JS dynamically. So far so good but I can't make it to get Div content attached to the popovers. They show up if I press the button but except of the headline they are just empty. Therefore I guess the problem lies in the `//Append newDiv to Popovercontent` - Part. But exactly with this function I am able to append div boxes to my popovers statically.

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <div id="div" style="display:none">
            <input type="checkbox"> Label 1</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox"> Label 2</input>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
         <button data-toggle="popover" id="btn1" data-original-title="Popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn1").popover({
   html: true,
   content: function() {
      return $("#div").html();
   }
});

var id = 2;

function addButton() {

//Creating HTML-Code for popovers
var newHTML = "<div style='display:none' id = 'newDiv" + id + "'>";
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    newHTML += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name" + id + i + "\">Label" + i + "</input><br>";
}
newHTML += "</div><button data-toggle=\"popover\" id=\"btn" + id + "\" data-original-title=\"Popover\" data-html=\"true\" data-placement=\"bottom\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" aria-label=\"Left Align\">";
newHTML += "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";

//Creating new Element
var trhtml = document.getElementById("table").insertRow();
var tdhtml = document.createElement("td");
tdhtml.style = "text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;";
tdhtml.innerHTML = newHTML;
trhtml.appendChild(tdhtml);

//Initialize new Popover
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

//Append newDiv to Popovercontent
$("#btn" + id).popover({
   html: true,
   content: function() {
      return $("#newDiv" + id).html();
  }
});

id=id+1;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be better if you add HTML markup also or create a fiddle

Comment: I am currently try to setup a fiddle but have some struggles to get the popover working. Added HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because are binding id inside popover content callback and then you are using variable id to create jquery selector   `$("#newDiv" + id).html()`

But the id variable is incremented each time, When the actual popover event called it receive id value NoOfRowInTable+1 for all popover content function calllback. 
For example if you have called addButton() 2 time the value of id inside popover content callback will be revived as 4 for all popover content callback function.

You can find a better explanation here

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Although for your example you don't need to make a hidden div with some id 
you can create html String for checkboxes and then add it to popover content callback .

Here is working demo

EDIT : Use .bind() to bind id properly

```js
$("#btn1").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $("#div").html();
  }
});

var id = 2;

$("#btn1").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $("#div").html();
  }
});

var id = 2;

function addButton() {

  //Creating HTML-Code for popovers
  var newHTML = "<div style='display:none' id = 'newDiv" + id + "'>";
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    newHTML += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name" + id + i + "\">Label" + i + "</input><br>";
  }
  newHTML += "</div><button data-toggle=\"popover\" id=\"btn" + id + "\" data-original-title=\"Popover\" data-html=\"true\" data-placement=\"bottom\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" aria-label=\"Left Align\">";
  newHTML += "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>";

  //Creating new Element
  var trhtml = document.getElementById("table").insertRow();
  //add empty first empty column
  var tdhtml0 = document.createElement("td");
  trhtml.appendChild(tdhtml0);
  var tdhtml1 = document.createElement("td");
  tdhtml1.style = "text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;";
  tdhtml1.innerHTML = newHTML;
  trhtml.appendChild(tdhtml1);



  //Append newDiv to Popovercontent
  $("#btn" + id).popover({
    html: true,
    content: function(id) {
      return $("#newDiv" + id).html();
    }.bind(this, id)
  });

  id = id + 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div" style="display:none">
        <input type="checkbox">Label 1
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox">Label 2
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
      <button data-toggle="popover" id="btn1" data-original-title="Popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addButton()">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: The problem is, that I need these DIVs because I link them to the Popover content so I can make the Popover Content persistent. Otherwise when I tick some boxes, close the popover and open it again, all ticks are gone. Now I put the code, where the DIV is loaded to the popover, into the newHTML Variable:
`newHTML += "<script>$(\"#btn" + id + "\").popover({html: true, content: function() {return $(\"#newDiv" + id + "\").html();}});";`
But this also doesn't work although in the HTML Source Code everything looks fine.

Comment: You can use .bind() to pass id value properly. I updated my answer check